# Scope of variables in php classes

Tags: php, class

I have this class, it does multiple things, but this is a simplified version of it so you can see what my problem is:

```
class WC_Product_Variation extends WC_Product {

    public $cliente_a="";

    public function __construct( $variation, $args = array() ) {

        //does some stuff to other variables

        if ( isset( $this->product_custom_fields['_cliente_a'][0] ) ) {
            $this->variation_has_cliente_a = true;
            $this->cliente_a               = $this->product_custom_fields['_cliente_a'][0];
        }
    }
    public function clientPrice($c){
        $aum=0;
        if($c=='customer'){$aum=$this->$cliente_a;}
        /*This should do more stuff but since 
        the basics aren't working I simplified to this*/
        return $aum;
    }
}
```

This class is from Woocommerce, if that changes anything, and I'm using it in wordpress, but basically what I'm doing is this:

```
 echo $_product->clientPrice('customer');
```

And that returns nothing, not even 0. Also, if I do

```
 echo $_product->cliente_a;
```

I get the proper value, which is 20. wtf?

EDIT:

I had a typo with the name of the variable in the question, but that's not the problem in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access member variables like this:

```
$this->cliente_c
```

**NOT** this: `$this->$cliente_c`

Comment: Thank you, I was blind to that $ symbol and I was going nuts.

Answer (score 1):

You clientPrice seems to return `cliente_c` and your other call returns `cliente_a`. Those could very well be different

```
 $aum=$this->$cliente_c;
```

shoudl be either

```
$aum=$this->cliente_c;
```

or

```
$aum=$this->cliente_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

the function `clientPrice` returns `$this->cliente_c` and is thus not the same as `$_product->cliente_a`

Comment: we don't know what's in `WC_Product`

Comment: Yeah yeah, I see, that's a typo. I have three variables, cliente_a b and c, I copied and pasted for the sake of simplicity, since I have to asign a different value depending on what is inside $c but all three variables are basically the same

Comment: Also WC_Product is another Woocommerce class, they both have multiple methods, this is just the part that I have added myself.